# Ho do you check if subquery records are in range outer fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

Two tables, `tbljob` and `tblscan`.

`tblJob` has three fields:

- `job_no`
- `job_start_seq`
- `job_end_seq`

`tblScan` has two fields:

- `serialnumber`
- `facility_id`

How do I query all the serial numbers for each job?

This is what I've come up with, but it's not correct.

```
SELECT     dbo.tblScan.facility_id, dbo.tblScan.serialnumber, dbo.tblJob.job_no
FROM         dbo.tblScan CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.tblJob
WHERE     EXISTS
               (SELECT     job_id, job_no, mailer, job_start_seq, job_end_seq
                FROM          dbo.tblJob AS tblJob_1
                WHERE      (dbo.tblScan.serialnumber BETWEEN job_start_seq AND job_end_seq))
```

Thanks to anyone that can help. I've got way to may hours in this. If you're wondering if the data structure can change, sadly, it cannot.

Comment: You sub-select doesn't make sense. You should just have a WHERE clause in the main SELECT.

Comment: how would I join the tables with no common data.  I need data from tblJob?

Answer (score 0):

I never used sql-server, but that being said, I would write something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.tblScan.facility_id, dbo.tblScan.serialnumber, dbo.tblJob.job_no
FROM   dbo.tblScan, dbo.tblJob
WHERE  dbo.tblScan.serialnumber BETWEEN job_start_seq AND job_end_seq
```

This will give you "duplicates" in terms of facility_id and job_no assuming you can have multiple serial numbers for each. Also the example uses your code but you may need to add some things such as `dbo.tblJob.` in front of job_start_seq and job_end_seq.

Now you have all the serial numbers, and you probably need to do a little work on your data depending on what you need to do with it.

FYI, this kind of statement is called a cross product.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have it working as needed.  Was way overthinking it. Guess I need to call it a night.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT TS.facility_id,TS.serialnumber,TJ.job_no
FROM dbo.tblScan TS CROSS JOIN  dbo.tblJob TJ ON
TS.serialnumber BETWEEN TJ.job_start_seq AND TJ.job_end_seq
```